# Docker on Centos 7 - "unkown flag: --ip-forward"

Tags: docker, containerd

I've installed docker on Centos 7 from the official docker-ce repository (followed instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/)). I'm seeing the following error when trying to start the docker service with `systemctl start docker`

```
Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
docker[24207]: unknown flag: --ip-forward
docker[24207]: See 'docker --help'.
docker[24207]: Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND
```

Here is the docker version:

```
[root@js03 englab]# docker --version
Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a leftover file from a previous version of docker at `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/service-overrides.conf` that was injecting environment variables into the docker.service ExecStart command.

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/service-overrides.conf
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-network
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon $OPTIONS \
      $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS \
      $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS \
      $BLOCK_REGISTRY \
      $INSECURE_REGISTRY
```

I removed this file and rebooted, then docker started successfully.